# Pyramid traversal

Tags: pyramid

I have a RootFactory defined as follows:

```
class RootFactory(object):
    __parent__ = None
    __name__ = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == "user":
            dispatch = UserSelector(self.request)
            dispatch.__name__ = key
            dispatch.__parent__ = self
            return dispatch

class UserSelector(object):
    __parent__ = None
    __name__ = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        dispatcher = UserDispatcher(self.request)
        dispatcher.__name__ = key
        dispatcher.__parent__ = self
        return dispatcher

class UserDispatcher(object):
    __parent__ = None
    __name__ = None

    def __init__(self, request):
        self.request = request

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        user = self.request.db.query(User)
        user = user.get(key)
        if not user:
            raise KeyError
        dispatcher = UserDispatcher(self.request)
        dispatcher.__name__ = key
        dispatcher.__parent__ = self
        dispatcher.user = user
        return dispatcher
```

This is from a project that I've inherited and I'm trying to figure out how this works. The project is a sql alchemy scaffold. So when a `GET` request comes in to `localhost:6543/user` an instance of `RootFactory` is created and the `__getitem__` method is executed. This returns an instance of `UserSelector`.

What causes the `__getitem__` to be executed in `UserSelector`?

Also if the request is a `PUT` or `POST` what instantiates the `UserDispatcher` object?

In my `UserViews` `UserDispatch` is passed as context for a `PUT` request. When I try to send a `PUT` I get `404 The resource could not be found. predicate mismatch` for view `UserViews (request_method = GET,HEAD)`. What does predicate refer to here?

Is it a problem with the PUT data?

Answer (score 0):

> What causes the `__getitem__` to be executed in `UserSelector`?

Your best bet is to read the [Pyramid Traversal](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html) documentation that describes how Traversal works.

So for a URL like this:

`/user/test/`

1. The traverser creates the root factory
2. The traverser takes the root factory, and takes the next URL element (`user`) and calls `__getitem__` on the root factory, this returns a new object
3. The traverser takes the next URL element (`test`) and calls `__getitem__` on the new object (in your case a `UserDispatcher`)

> Also if the request is a `PUT` or `POST` what instantiates the `UserDispatcher` object?

The traversal is done before your view lookup begins, and is strictly based upon every element in the URL that sits in between two slashes.

`/user/test/posts/` has 3 elements (`user`, `test`, `posts`). So your `UserDispatcher` will only ever be instantiated when the URL can traverse to it.

> What does predicate refer to here?

Predicate here refers to the various restrictions you have set on your view. When you told Pyramid that the view could only execute for `GET` or `HEAD` (the default) it will reject all other HTTP verbs. When Pyramid looks up what view to execute for an incoming request it will attempt to match the predicates. Now if a view could have worked, except one or more of its predicates don't match, an error is raised, this error is only raised if it has exhausted looking for possible matches.

Once the error is raised, it is propagated through Pyramid and ultimately leads to a `404 - Not Found` error. If you wish for a view to match your `PUT` request, you will want to modify the predicates.